# eMMC error on the platform happened in different country

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, sd-card

Kernel version: 3.4.91

OS: WindRiver IDP-XT 2.0.4.29

CPU: Intel Quark

Hi,

The device works well at my side. However, when I shipped it to my friend in different country, the system failed to boot and some weird message appeared.

```
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 675376, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): using internal journal
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 1575944, nr 8, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2774816, nr 160, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00
mmcblk0: retrying using single block read
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2774837, nr 139, cmd response 0x900, card status 0x0
end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2774837
mmcblk0: error -110 sending status command, retrying
mmcblk0: timed out sending r/w cmd command, card status 0x800900
mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x900, card status 0x40800b00
mmcblk0: error -84 transferring data, sector 2363904, nr 16, cmd response 0x900, card status 0xc00
end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2363905
end_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2363912
Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p2.
EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): error: ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): error: remounting filesystem read-only
```

Symptom: The entire system becomes "Read-Only".

Obviously there are something wrong with the SD card. 
However, it does not happen here. 
I have no idea where is the starting point to debug because I sent him another SD card and the story doesnt change.

Could the voltage might be the root cause to this issue ?
(Power supply ?)

Please advise.

Comment: There might be some problem in his board. check power and clock of interface.

Comment: @JagsVG I also shipped the new board that I've fully tested in my side. Unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Comment: @JagsVG How can I check the clock of interface ?

Comment: Regarding few of the warnings; refer to the post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87409/what-does-mounting-fs-with-errors-mean-in-dmesg-and-what-to-do-after-that

Comment: What country are you from and what country did you ship the board to? Perhaps the power supply is not correct for the target country, different countries have different mains electric characteristics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country